# PowerPivot Slicer Not Refreshing after VBA Filter

Tags: vba, excel, filter, powerpivot

I am trying to use a macro to filter a pivot table using the below code snippet. The code works, however the Slicer does not update to reflect the filter that was just applied.  If I manually filter the pivot table, the slice does update.

I tried refresh/refresh all, manual update settings, and screen update settings.  I am stuck.  Any ideas?

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "[DataWithDuplicates_FULL].[PA_Select].[PA_Select]"). _
   PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=SrchTrm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slicer works by looking at whether or not the `PivotItem` is visible or not. Using the `PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains` kind of strategy will appropriately filter your data but will not "check" the right filter boxes.

The way to get filters/slicers to respond in the way you want is like

```
Dim pf  As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim pt As PivotTable

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("[DataWithDuplicates_FULL].[PA_Select].[PA_Select]")
pf.ClearAllFilters
For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
    pi.Visible = pi.Caption Like "*" & SrchTrm & "*"
Next pi
```

Careful about selecting *no* values because the pivot table will throw an error when you tell it to select nothing.